# how to call method when date is set using datepicker in Android

Tags: android

I have created an application in which I have an EditText and a Button "show".
When the EditText is clicked Date Picker pop ups and date can be selected and set to EditText. On clicking the show Button, all details on that date will display. This is working but I need to remove this Button "show" and when `Date` is set, automatically details should display? How can I do it without Button onclick?

```
datetxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String temp = datetxt.getText().toString();
        if (s.equals(datetxt)) {
            "My codes"
    }
```

This is what I tried. It's not working.

Comment: Where you want to show your date details?

Comment: just below that ... that all i have set textviews. that is working.
But i need to remove that show button. after setting date automatically all details should display.

Comment: Can you show your datepicker code? Is that datepicker or date picker dialog?

Answer (score 0):

if your are using DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener there is a method :

```
@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth){

    // add your button hidig code here


           }
```